# Pass jsonArray to js android

Tags: android, json

I have a problem with `android and js`. I pass `jsonArray` in

`JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(defaultTypesName);
"javascript:showParams('"+jsonArray+"')");`

but js see my jsonArray as String. On iOS see like object but from android see as String. How can I pass jSONArray to js as to js see this as Object?

Comment: JsonArray is an object in Java/Android. However, in Javascript there is no concept of a JSONArray object. In Javascript you just have a JSON object, which is actually a string.

Comment: Try to parse string to object like var jsonAry = $.parseJSON(params); using jquery...